# How to change the values and do the functions Newton-Raphson

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I need to iterate Newton-Raphson in MATLAB. It seems easy but I cannot figure out where I am wrong. The problem is:

For mmm=1:
1) If m=1 take c1=c1b and c2=1-c1 and do the loop for u1,2(i) and p1,2(i)

2)If m=2 take c1=c1+dc and c2=1-c1, and this time do the loop with new c1 and c2 for u1,2(i) and p1,2(i)

3) If m=3 take c1=(c1*st(1)-(c1-dc)*st(2))/(st(1)-st(2)) and do the loop for new c1 and c2.

Then increase the iteration number: mmm=2 ;
mmm keeps count of the number of N-R iterations. The first iteration has mmm=1, the second mmm=2, etc. (This particular run only do 2 iterations).
sumint are inside of the integrals.

I need to plot these figures in the code but MATLAB gives errors below. Please help me.

Relevant part of the code:

```
ii=101;
   u = cell(2, 1);
ini_cond = [0,0];
for i = 1:2;
   u{i} = zeros(1,ii);
   u{i}(:, ii) = ini_cond(i) * rand(1, 1);
end    


for i=1:ii;
        fikness=fik*sin(pi.*x);
        u{1}(i)=(c1-H1D*(x-0.5)+AD/2.*(x-0.5).^2)./(H1-0.5*fikness-A*(x-0.5));
        u{2}(i)=(c2+H1D*(x-0.5)-AD/2.*(x-0.5).^2)./(1.-H1+0.5*fikness+A*(x-0.5)); 
end

p = cell(2, 1);
q = cell(2, 1);


for i = 1:2;
   p{i} = zeros(1,ii);
   q{i} = zeros(1,ii);
end    

p{1}(1)=0.5*(1.-u{1}(1).^2);
q{1}(1)=0;
p{2}(1)=0.5*(1.-u{2}(1).^2);
q{2}(1)=0;

for i=2:101

q{1}(i)=q{1}(i-1)-dx*(u{1}(i-1)-ub{1}(i-1))./dt;
p{1}(i)=0.5*(1.-u{1}(i).^2)+q{1}(i);
q{2}(i)=q{2}(i-1)-dx*(u{2}(i-1)-ub{2}(i-1))./dt;
p{2}(i)=0.5*(1.-u{2}(i).^2)+q{2}(i);

end


st = zeros(2, length(t));
st(1,:)=p{1}(100)-p{2}(100);
m=m+1;

if m==3; 
c1=(c1*st(1)-(c1-dc)*st(2))/(st(1)-st(2));
c2=1-c1;
end
for i = 1:2;
   sumint{i} = zeros(1,length(t));
end 
sumint = cell(2, 1);
sumint{1}(1)=0.5*(p{2}(1)-p{1}(1));
sumint{2}(1)=0.5*(p{2}(1)-p{1}(1)).*(-1/2);

for i=2:ii-1;
x=(i-1)*dx;
sumint{1}(i)=sumint{1}(i-1)+(p{2}(i)-p{1}(i));
sumint{2}(i)=sumint{2}(i-1)+(p{2}(i)-p{1}(i))*(x-1/2);

end

H1DDOT=-sumint{1}.*dx./rmass;
H1D=H1D+dt*H1DDOT;
H1=H1+dt*H1D;
ADDOT=sumint{2}*dx./rmomi;
AD=AD+dt*ADDOT;
A=A+dt*AD;

H1L=H1+A.*0.5;
H1R=H1-A.*0.5;
H2=1.-H1;
rat1=AD./ADinit;
rat2=ADDOT./AD;
```

u are the velocities p are the pressures c1,c2 are the camber effects H1DDOT and ADDOT are the second derivation of H1 and A. sum1 and sum2 are the inside of the integrals to define the values of H1DDOT and ADDOT. H1DDOT and ADDOT are functions of time.

Comment: I mean my target is to find out how can I change the variables c1, c2 and put them into all u1,2(i) s and pressures p1,2 (i) ss then compute H1D,H1DDOT and AD, ADDOT..   Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the message, the error is with this line:

```
sumint{2}(i)=sumint{2}(i-1)+(p{2}(i)-p{1}(i)).*(x-1/2);
```

Now, let's find out why:

```
sumint{2}(i) = ...
```

This part means you want to insert whatever is on the right side to the `i`th position of the array in cell `sumint{2}`. That means, the right side must be a scalar.

Is it?

Well, `sumint{2}(i-1)+(p{2}(i)-p{1}(i))` is certainly a scalar, since you use a single value as index to all the vectors/arrays. The problem is the multiplication `.*(x-1/2);`.

From the code above, it is clear that `x` is a vector / array, (since you use `length(x)` etc). Multiplying the scalar `sumint{2}(i-1)+(p{2}(i)-p{1}(i))`, by the vector `x`, will give you back a vector, which as mentioned, will not work.

Maybe you want the `i`th value of `x`?

There are several other strange things going on in your code, for instance:

```
for i=1:101;
        fikness=fik*sin(pi.*x);
        u{1}=(c1-H1D*(x-0.5)+AD/2.*(x-0.5).^2)./(H1-0.5*fikness-A*(x-0.5));
        u{2}=(c2+H1D*(x-0.5)-AD/2.*(x-0.5).^2)./(1.-H1+0.5*fikness+A*(x-0.5)); 
end
```

Why do you have a loop here? You are not looping anything, you are doing the same calculations 100 times. Again, I guess it should be `x(i)`.

## Update:

Your new error is introduced because you changed `x` into a scalar. Then `u = zeros(1,length(x))` will only be a scalar, meaning `u{1}(i)` will fail for `i ~= 1`.

Comment: thank yuou very much for your answer. I change the code x is not a vecto any more:)but matlab says when I run it :   ??? Attempted to access u.%cell(2); index out of bounds because
numel(u.%cell)=1.      PLease how can I fix the problem
   
Error in ==> grab3_SmithWilson at 79
p{1}(i)=0.5*(1.-u{1}(i).^2)+q{1}(i);

Comment: @user3115779: See update. I'm pretty sure you want to keep `x` as a vector.

Comment: yes you are quite right but I had already changed the velocity as u = zeros(1,101) and add the line x=(i-1)*dx in every loop. Thus my x is sclara now and in every iteration it changes with the amount of dx. But again the same error. I do not understand obviously..

Comment: @user3115779: If you have done changes, please update the question with the new information. Please keep the question as it is now, but include the new information at the bottom (as I did with the update).